# Mosquitto MQTT Client return error 10 in loop_start function call after connect call

Tags: c++, mqtt, publish-subscribe, mosquitto, libmosquitto

I'm writing an MQTT client which simply connects to the broker, and publishes or subscribes to a topic.
Here in the program, I try to Connect to Broker and then call the **loop_forever()** function and is execute successfully and gets a connect acknowledgment at the client side, but instead of **loop_forever()**, when I called the  **loop_Start()** for the new thread to execute all callback, it failed with the error **MOSQ_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED**.
Here is a code for the MQTT client for publisher and subscriber.

**myMosq.h**

```
#include <mosquittopp.h>
#include <mosquitto.h>

class myMosq : public mosqpp::mosquittopp
{
private:
    const char* host;
    const char* id;
    const char* topic;
    int         port;
    int         keepalive;

    void on_connect(int rc);
    void on_disconnect(int rc);
    void on_publish(int mid);
    void on_message(const struct mosquitto_message* message);

public:
    myMosq(const char* id, const char* _topic, const char* host, int port);
    ~myMosq();
    bool send_message(const char* _message);
};
```

**myMosq.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

myMosq::myMosq(const char* _id, const char* _topic, const char* _host, int _port) : mosquittopp(_id)
{
    mosqpp::lib_init() ;        // Mandatory initialization for mosquitto library

    this->keepalive = 60;    // Basic configuration setup for myMosq class
    this->id = _id;
    this->port = _port;
    this->host = _host;
    this->topic = _topic;

    int result;
    result = connect_async(host, port, keepalive);     // non blocking connection to broker request
    if (result != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error in connect_async" << std::endl;
    }
    result = loop_start();            // Start thread managing connection / publish/subscribe
    //result = loop_forever();            // Start thread managing connection / publish / subscribe
    if (result != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error in loop_start: " << (mosq_err_t)result << std::endl;
    }
};

myMosq::~myMosq() 
{
    loop_stop();            // Kill the thread
    mosqpp::lib_cleanup();    // Mosquitto library cleanup
}

bool myMosq::send_message(const  char* _message)
{
    int ret = publish(NULL, this->topic, strlen(_message), _message, 1, false);
    return (ret == MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS);
}

void myMosq::on_disconnect(int rc) 
{
    std::cout << ">> myMosq - disconnection(" << rc << ")" << std::endl;
}

void myMosq::on_connect(int rc)
{
    if (rc == 0){
        std::cout << ">> myMosq - connected with server" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << ">> myMosq - Impossible to connect with server(" << rc << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}

void myMosq::on_publish(int mid)
{
    std::cout << ">> myMosq - Message (" << mid << ") succeed to be published " << std::endl;
}

void myMosq::on_message(const struct mosquitto_message* message)
{
    std::cout << "Topic: " << message->topic << " Payload: " << message->payload << " Payload_Length: " << message->payloadlen << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

#include "myMosq.h"

void MQTT_Subscriber(myMosq& i_client)
{
    int result = i_client.subscribe(nullptr, "logrequest", 1);
    if (result != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "mosquitto : subscriber error: " << mosqpp::strerror(result) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "mosquitto : subscriber : " << result << std::endl;
    }
}

void MQTT_Publisher(myMosq& i_client)
{
    int i = 1;
    std::string message = "I am mosquitto VS pub";
    while (1)
    {
        std::string message1 = message + std::to_string(i);
        if (!i_client.send_message(message1.c_str()))
        {
            break;
        }
        Sleep(2000);
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "In main" << std::endl;

    std::shared_ptr<myMosq> m_client = std::make_shared<myMosq>("dev3_", "logrequest", "127.0.0.1", 1883);

    //MQTT_Publisher(m_client);
    //MQTT_Subscriber(m_client);

    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

I used visual studio 2022 and added all mosquito dependencies to the project.
while running program with the loop_start() function I get this error:
`**Error in loop_start: 10**`

Comment: [The docs](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html#mosquitto_loop_start) say "MOSQ_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED if thread support is not available". So my guess would be you are using a library compiled without thread support (which [appears](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2707) to be the case with the default Windows installation).

Comment: So what configuration required to support thread brits?

Comment: Confirmation of the above is [here](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/README-windows.txt) "libmosquitto on Windows is currently compiled without thread support"... You will need to build from source; instructions are [here](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto#building-from-source). Note that threading under windows relies on the "old pthreads-win32" so there may be issues (there is a reason the standard build does not include it) - version 2.1 should [reintroduce this](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/develop/ChangeLog.txt#L152).

Comment: Yes Brits, Thanks for your answer, I build the mosquitto lib manually with Pthread-win32 in Windows and can run the MQTT client for subscribe and publish.
@Brits: Is Mosquitto MQTT Client automatically reconnected if Broker goes down and up again? Any Idea about it? I used the loop_start() for thread other than the main thread.

Comment: Yes - see [the docs](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html#mosquitto_reconnect). I'll add an answer to close off this question.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html#mosquitto_loop_start) say `loop_Start()` returns "MOSQ_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED if thread support is not available". This will [be because](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/README-windows.txt) "libmosquitto on Windows is currently compiled without thread support". This means you will need to rebuild the library with thread support ([instructions](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto#building-from-source)).

This should [no longer be necessary](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/develop/ChangeLog.txt#L152) when version 2.1 is released.